# How to make page non-cacheable in cms

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-session, block-cache

I have added below code to load custom template file from cms.

```
<p>{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Testblock" template="Vendor_Module::test_template.phtml"}}</p>
```

If template is loaded in xml file i can use `cacheable="false"` then page will no cached.

so how to add same functionality in cms?

Because i am trying to get logged in customer details. but this is not retrieving since page is cached i guess.

All i am looking to get customer details.
Used below code and injected  this class

```
 \Magento\Customer\Model\Session

return $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
```

Can anyone look into this and suggest me.

Comment: You can refer this for get logged in customer detail from session.  https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-get-customer-data-from-session-when-cache-enabled/

Comment: @PragnadeepPitroda, customer session is not working since it is cached, so pls help me in getting customer session else avoid page being cached

Answer (score 3):

You can set in your `default.xml` layout file.

Path : `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="content"> 
 <block name="test" cacheable="false"/> 
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: only working solution in 2021 for me - thanks

Comment: Please do not do this, it will render your entire site uncacheable as default.xml is included in all pages and `cacheable="false"` makes entire page uncacheable.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging You can disable cache from magento admin panel ( Settings->Cache Management select all, next select Disable instead of Refresh and click Submit )

Or type this command in terminal: 
**bin/magento cache:disable**

But in your situation i think that clearing cache is enough:

**bin/magento cache:clean**

**bin/magento cache:flush**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the complete page non-cacheable then you can try cacheable attribute in any block. Blocks can be set as non-cacheable by setting the **cacheable** attribute **false** in layout XML files. For example:

```
<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" cacheable="false" />
```

Pages containing such blocks are not cached.

**Reference :** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html

Comment: this works if we used from file but my question is how to use in cms

Comment: @jafarpinjar - You have to extend the cms module and add the headers info on controller execute action based on page id. This is another way to make the specific cms page as non-cacheable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the option of sections in magento 2. You can load the specific block elements via sections on fully cached page. Its something similar to your mini-cart feature on home page header. The home page was cached fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cacheable="false" and it will working fine.

```
<p>{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Testblock" template="Vendor_Module::test_template.phtml" cacheable="false"}}</p>
```

Hope it help!

Comment: this does not work for me

Comment: this is not working